# How to get month name 12 months back with asp classic?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I want to display the short name for each month, 12 months back from the previous month, but with the below I get an error on mon1 and mon2 and I guess since that is last year?

```
    mon1=MonthName(Month(Now())-11,1)
    mon2=MonthName(Month(Now())-10,1)
    mon3=MonthName(Month(Now())-9,1)
    mon4=MonthName(Month(Now())-8,1)
    mon5=MonthName(Month(Now())-7,1)
    mon6=MonthName(Month(Now())-6,1)
    mon7=MonthName(Month(Now())-5,1)
    mon8=MonthName(Month(Now())-4,1)
    mon9=MonthName(Month(Now())-3,1)
    mon10=MonthName(Month(Now())-2,1)
    mon11=MonthName(Month(Now())-1,1)
    mon12=MonthName(Month(Now()),1)
```

So how can I display now,dec,jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct
Thanks.

Comment: The output of the `Month()` function is an integer between 1 and 12. You need to minus the number of months from `Now()` first before wrapping it with `Month()` which you can do with `DateAdd()`, just pass it a negative month interval.

Comment: Thanks Lankymart, I got it working with d1 = DateAdd("m", -11, date) and mon1=MonthName(Month(d1),1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the `Month()` function returns an integer between 1 and 12 to represent each month. Instead you want to minus the number of months from the `Now()` value before wrapping it with `Month()`.

Below is an example that does this using a `For` loop and a single dimension `Array`.

```vb
Dim dt: dt = Now()
Dim i, mon(12)
Const numOfMonths = 12

For i = 1 To numOfMonths
  mon(i) = MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", i - numOfMonths, dt)), True)
Next

Call Response.Write(Join(mon, vbCrLf))
```

Output:

```
Sep
Aug
Jul
Jun
May
Apr
Mar
Feb
Jan
Dec
Nov
Oct
```